# Trying to extract from the deep node with scrapy, results are bad

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

As a beginner I'm having a hard time, so I'm here to ask for help.
I'm trying to extract prices from the html page, which are nested deeply:

[image]

second price location:

[image]

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from mymarket.items import MymarketItem

class MySpider(Spider):
    name = "mymarket"
    allowed_domains = ["url"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://url"
            ]

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        titles = sel.xpath('//table[@class="tab_product_list"]//tr')
        items = []
        for t in titles:
            item = MymarketItem()
            item["price"] = t.xpath('//tr//span[2]/text()').extract()
            items.append(item)

        return items
```

I'm trying to export scraped prices to csv. they do export but are being populated like this:

[image]

And I want them to be sorted like this in .csv:

[image]
etc.

Can anybody point out where is the faulty part of the xpath or how I can make prices be sorted "properly" ?

Comment: Are you aware that `item["price"] = t.xpath('//tr//span[2]/text()').extract()` will search on the whole page, not only inside a title? You should use `'.//tr//span[2]/text()'`

Comment: Well, current xpath that I have in script does search only for the prices. Weird thing is that it outputs the prices csv in one cell. See the updated question. I just can't figure out how to sort them per row as I have indicated in the question.

Comment: It's very difficult to figure out just looking at the picture. Having a web page to test would be much better

Comment: @warwaruk There is it: http://www.mymarket.ge/main.php?cPath=13

Comment: I would hook on `style="color:red;"`: `//table[@class="tab_product_list"]//span[@style="color:red;"]`

Comment: @warwaruk Thanks. The results are same:

http://imgur.com/q0H0OTr

Comment: Are you using exactly the same code as in your question?

Comment: @warwaruk Sure. just updated the xpath according to your advice.

Comment: See the code in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to say what's wrong with the path. Install `firepath` extension for Firefox to test your `xpath` queries. One note for now:

```
titles = sel.xpath('//table[@class="tab_product_list"]//tr')
```

In your screenshot you have nested tables, so `//tr` will give `tr`s from nested tables too.

```
def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        titles = sel.xpath('//table[@class="tab_product_list"]/tr')  # or with tbody
        items = []
        for t in titles:
            item = MymarketItem()
            item["price"] = t.xpath('.//span[@style="color:red;"]/text()').extract()[0]
            items.append(item)

        return items
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Right now I'm having a problem with outputting the prices into csv. All prices go into one cell, and after adding `[0]` after `.extract()` it prints only the first price separated in cells.

Comment: If you could edit your question to include the full spider code, the current output of your CSV and the required output, then that would help people provide a more focused answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

`.extract()` returns a list, even if just one argument found, take the first element of the list `.extract()[0]`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Thing is, that `.extract()[0]` returns results with only the first price item populated pet row and doesn't add other prices.